# Configuração Java no linux fedora

Tags: java, linux

Estou configurando o JAVA e o ANT no linux fedora, seguindo alguns passos que encontrei na internet, pois eu nunca fiz isso no linux.
Eu os configuro pelo terminal pois estou acessando a maquina pelo SSH.
Estou configurando da seguinte maneira:

```
export ANT_HOME=/root/Desktop/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.7.1

export JAVA_HOME=/root/bea/jdk160_05

export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin

export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

porem quando faço

```
java -version
```

aparece

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora-2.4.4.1.fc20-x86_64 u51-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

O java que estou configurando é o  1.6.0_05.

e quando eu faço o seguinte comando

```
javac -version
```

a versão que aparece é

```
javac 1.6.0_05
```

Eu gostaria de saber porque quando dou um java -version naõ é a versão 1.6.0_05 que aparece.

PS: Não se preocupe quanto a versão do java, eu estou fazendo uns testes e estava tentando configurar o java anterior mesmo

Comment: Nos sistemas debian tem uma lance de _java alterantives_... Dá um procurada sobre isso. É para você alternar entre as versões do Java e escolher uma default, se não me engano.

Comment: Se queres forçar o path escolhe a ordem pretendida: `export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: @JJoao Funcionou o que vc disse, interessante, eu pensava que fazendo o `export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin` Ja colocava na frente.

Comment: @IgorVenturelli obrigado pela dica, eu dei uma olhada breve parece ser interessante

Comment: Para saber qual java está sendo chamado: `which java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remova o OpenJDK.
2. baixe o JDK no site da Oracle e descompacte o pacote na sua pasta de preferência, no meu caso utilizo /usr/local/java.
3. utilize o update-alternatives para configurar o executável, como no exemplo a seguir:
   `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "caminho_do_jdk/bin/java" 1`
4. repita a operação para o javac e o javaws.
5. Crie e exporte seu *JAVA_HOME* dentro do seu arquivo de configuração do terminal (bashrc, zshrc etc).